# How to access relation imageName in twig (using VichUploaderBundle)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

I have an issue with `{{app.user}}` and `Entity` relation.
My user has a ManyToOne relation with an entity `CustomerGroup`:

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CustomerGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $CustomerGroup;

...
```

My `CustomerGroup` Entity uses VichUploaderBundle :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerGroupRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable

 */
 class CustomerGroup
 {
    /**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="customer_logo", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 *
 * @var integer
 */
private $imageSize;

public function __construct(?File $imageFile = null)
{
    $this->customerEntities = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->masterTypes = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->deployModels = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

    if (null !== $imageFile) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->dateUpd = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
}

/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $imageFile
 */
public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

    if (null !== $imageFile) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->dateUpd = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
}

public function getImageFile(): ?File
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

public function setImageName(?string $imageName): void
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;
}

public function getImageName(): ?string
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

public function setImageSize(?int $imageSize): void
{
    $this->imageSize = $imageSize;
}

public function getImageSize(): ?int
{
    return $this->imageSize;
}
```

In my Twig template, I want to access the CustomerGroup's imageName from the user. What I tried :
`{{ app.user.CustomerGroup.imageName }}` -> `null`

`{{ app.user.getCustomerGroup().getImageName() }}` -> `null`

But, if I do : `{{ app.user.CustomerGroup.name}} --> I get the correct value

When I dump `{{app.user}}` :

```
User^ {#824 ▼
  -id: 1
  -email: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  -roles: array:1 [▶]
  -password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  -CustomerGroup: CustomerGroup^ {#809 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 1
    -name: null
    -abbreviation: null
    -isActive: null
    -customerEntities: null
    -dateAdd: null
    -dateUpd: null
    -createdBy: null
    -modifiedBy: null
    -models: null
    -masterTypes: null
    -documents: null
    -deployModels: null
    -imageFile: null
    -imageName: null
    -imageSize: null
     …2
  }
  -CustomerEntity: CustomerEntity^ {#754 ▶}
  -customerSites: PersistentCollection^ {#842 ▶}
  -dateAdd: DateTime @1566424800 {#827 ▶}
  -dateUpd: DateTime @1566579539 {#826 ▶}
  -createdBy: User^ {#824}
  -modifiedBy: User^ {#824}
  -firstName: "xxxxx"
  -lastName: "xxxxxx"
  -isActive: true
  -isDeleted: false
}
```

If I Dump `app.user.CustomerGroup`:

```
CustomerGroup^ {#809 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 1
  -name: null
  -abbreviation: null
  -isActive: null
  -customerEntities: null
  -dateAdd: null
  -dateUpd: null
  -createdBy: null
  -modifiedBy: null
  -models: null
  -masterTypes: null
  -documents: null
  -deployModels: null
  -imageFile: null
  -imageName: null
  -imageSize: null
   …2
}
```

The first try only works when I'm on a controller that returns the `CustomerGroup` entity.

Thanks for your help

Best,

Julien

Comment: Could you give us more details by making a dump, here `{{ dump(app.user) }}`  in your twig template?

Comment: @qdequippe : that's done ! Thanks

Comment: thanks! just to check now `{{ dump(app.user.CustomerGroup) }}`

Comment: Done ! Just to be clear, if I do `{{app.user.CustomerGroup.name}}`, it works !

Comment: could you try EXTRA_LAZY loading on CustomGroup in User, here the doc https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html and tell me the results

Comment: I added EXTRA_LAZY like that : `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CustomerGroup", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")` and the result is the same !

Comment: :/ last chance try to dump `{{ dump(app.user.CustomerGroup.imageName) }}`

Comment: I have null when dumping imageName...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ackward solution !
If I want the `imageName` property to be loaded, I have to load the `CustomerGroup` relation somewhere IN the template. This way, the entity is loaded and I can access the `imageName` property.

Example :
`{{app.user.CustomerGroup.imageName}}` ==> result `null`

```
{{app.user.CustomerGroup.name}}
{{app.user.CustomerGroup.imageName}}
```

Results in :
`Customer1`
`Customer1.png`

So, I call the `CustomerGroup.name` somewhere in the top of my twig file (in the body class for example and then I can call the `imageName` property.